# Tar Create and Split files into subdir

Tags: bash, tar, split

I have this command:

```
tar -cf - input/* | split --bytes=1m
```

Which splits my huge gz files into small ones. This works fine.

However I want the output (the small files) to be created in the `input/` directory. How to achieve?

Comment: A simple question, why are you splitting the archive into such small parts? Apart from putting them onto floppy drives, I don't see much reason for this. This may be a XY problem, there may be a much better solution for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe into a subshell and call `cd` in there:

```
tar -cf - input/* | ( cd input; split --bytes=1m )
```

Just be careful to not call this twice, because the next time, the small files will be part of the `tar` archive too. It's generally not a good idea to put the archive back into the original directory.

Also, your `tar` command is currently not compressing, you are just putting files together and splitting them apart again into same-sized chunks.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I want to do. I do not want to compress at all. Anything against using this tehcnique as subprocess call in a python script?

Comment: It should work with `os.system` if your `$SHELL` is set to `bash` or something similar. However, it's much cleaner to put this into a shell script that takes a directory for an argument, and use `from subprocess import call`.